# Purpose of cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty

Tags: jetty, cxf

I want to understand the purpose of below dependency while developing cxf webservices.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Without adding this dependency CXF simple frontend doesn't create the service.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jetty provides a Web server and javax.servlet container for your CXF services.
Adding the dependency above is like embedding the container into your application.

Alternatively, you can add this dependency using **test** scope in order to unit test your web services and deploy your application into an external container.

Please refer to http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transports.html for more information about available CXF transports.